# Varnish-4 always returns x-cache: pass uncacheable

Tags: varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I'm currently setting up Varnish 4 for my domain for post request. But I can't figure out, why the request is always a "MISS" and I get x-cache as pass uncacheable.

Varnish Version

```
varnishd (varnish-4.1.11 revision 61367ed17d08a9ef80a2d42dc84caef79cdeee7a)
Copyright (c) 2006 Verdens Gang AS
Copyright (c) 2006-2019 Varnish Software AS
```

Where my VCL file is

```
vcl 4.0;

import std;
import bodyaccess;

backend default {
  .host = "X.X.X.X";
  .port = "80";
}

sub vcl_recv {
        unset req.http.x-cache;
        unset req.http.X-Body-Len;

        if (req.method == "POST") {
                std.log("Will cache POST for: " + req.http.host + req.url);
                std.cache_req_body(3000KB);
                set req.http.X-Body-Len = bodyaccess.len_req_body();
                set req.http.Content-Length =  bodyaccess.len_req_body();

                if (req.http.X-Body-Len == "-1") {
                        return(synth(400, "The request body size exceeds the li$
                }
                return (hash);
        }
}

sub vcl_hash {
    # To cache POST and PUT requests
std.syslog(9,"vcl hash "+ req.http.X-Body-Len);
     bodyaccess.hash_req_body();

}

sub vcl_backend_fetch {

if(bereq.http.X-Body-Len){
        set bereq.method = "POST";
        }

}

sub vcl_backend_response {
  if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
        beresp.http.Set-Cookie ||
        beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
        (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&
        beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store|private") ||
        beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
        /*
         * Mark as "Hit-For-Pass" for the next 2 minutes
         */
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    }
return (deliver);

}

sub vcl_deliver {
std.syslog(9, "response status "+ resp.status);


}

sub vcl_hit {
        set req.http.x-cache = "hit";
}

sub vcl_miss {
        set req.http.x-cache = "miss";
}

sub vcl_pass {
        set req.http.x-cache = "pass";
}

sub vcl_pipe {
        set req.http.x-cache = "pipe uncacheable";
}

sub vcl_synth {
        set resp.http.x-cache = "synth synth";
}

sub vcl_deliver {
        if (obj.uncacheable) {
                set req.http.x-cache = req.http.x-cache + " uncacheable" ;
        } else {
                set req.http.x-cache = req.http.x-cache + " cached" ;
        }
        set resp.http.x-cache = req.http.x-cache;
}
```

if you see VarnishLog

```
 32833 Link           c req 32834 rxreq
     32835 Begin          b bereq 32834 pass
     32835 Timestamp      b Start: 1585506203.103807 0.000000 0.000000
     32835 BereqMethod    b POST
     32835 BereqURL       b /XYZ/
     32835 BereqProtocol  b HTTP/1.1
     32835 BereqHeader    b Content-Type: application/json
     32835 BereqHeader    b Accept-Language: en-US
     32835 BereqHeader    b User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.24.0
     32835 BereqHeader    b Accept: */*
     32835 BereqHeader    b Host: X.X.X.X
     32835 BereqHeader    b Content-Length: 161
     32835 BereqHeader    b X-Forwarded-For: Y.Y.Y.Y
     32835 BereqHeader    b X-Body-Len: 161
     32835 BereqHeader    b Accept-Encoding: gzip
     32835 BereqHeader    b x-cache: pass
     32835 BereqHeader    b X-Varnish: 32835
     32835 VCL_call       b BACKEND_FETCH
     32835 BereqMethod    b POST
     32835 VCL_return     b fetch
     32835 Timestamp      b Bereq: 1585506203.105855 0.002048 0.002048
     32835 Timestamp      b Beresp: 1585506205.155543 2.051736 2.049688
     32835 BerespProtocol b HTTP/1.1
     32835 BerespStatus   b 200
     32835 BerespReason   b OK
     32835 BerespHeader   b Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400
     32835 BerespHeader   b Content-Type: application/json
     32835 BerespHeader   b Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
     32835 BerespHeader   b Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
     32835 BerespHeader   b X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
     32835 BerespHeader   b X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
     32835 BerespHeader   b Date: Sun, 29 Mar 2020 18:23:21 GMT
     32835 BerespHeader   b Content-Length: 1499
     32835 TTL            b RFC 86400 10 -1 1585506205 1585506205 1585506201 0 86400
     32835 VCL_call       b BACKEND_RESPONSE
     32835 TTL            b VCL 120 10 0 1585506205
     32835 VCL_return     b deliver
     32835 Storage        b malloc Transient
     32835 ObjProtocol    b HTTP/1.1
     32835 ObjStatus      b 200
     32835 ObjReason      b OK
     32835 ObjHeader      b Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400
     32835 ObjHeader      b Content-Type: application/json
     32835 ObjHeader      b Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
     32835 ObjHeader      b Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
     32835 ObjHeader      b X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
     32835 ObjHeader      b X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
     32835 ObjHeader      b Date: Sun, 29 Mar 2020 18:23:21 GMT
     32835 ObjHeader      b Content-Length: 1499
     32835 Fetch_Body     b 3 length stream
     32835 BackendReuse   b 24 boot.default
     32835 Timestamp      b BerespBody: 1585506205.155630 2.051823 0.000087
     32835 Length         b 1499
     32835 BereqAcct      b 343 161 504 318 1499 1817
     32835 End            b
     32834 Begin          c req 32833 rxreq
     32834 Timestamp      c Start: 1585506203.103709 0.000000 0.000000
     32834 Timestamp      c Req: 1585506203.103709 0.000000 0.000000
     32834 ReqStart       c Y.Y.Y.Y 50188
     32834 ReqMethod      c POST
     32834 ReqURL         c /XYZ/
     32834 ReqProtocol    c HTTP/1.1
     32834 ReqHeader      c Content-Type: application/json
     32834 ReqHeader      c Accept-Language: en-US
     32834 ReqHeader      c User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.24.0
     32834 ReqHeader      c Accept: */*
     32834 ReqHeader      c Host: X.X.X.X
     32834 ReqHeader      c Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
     32834 ReqHeader      c Connection: keep-alive
     32834 ReqHeader      c Content-Length: 161
     32834 ReqHeader      c X-Forwarded-For: Y.Y.Y.Y
     32834 VCL_call       c RECV
     32834 Storage        c malloc Transient
     32834 Timestamp      c ReqBody: 1585506203.103769 0.000060 0.000060
     32834 Debug          c "VRT_CacheReqBody(3072000): 161"
     32834 ReqHeader      c X-Body-Len: 161
     32834 VCL_return     c hash
     32834 ReqUnset       c Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
     32834 ReqHeader      c Accept-Encoding: gzip
     32834 VCL_call       c HASH
     32834 VCL_return     c lookup
     32834 Debug          c "XXXX HIT-FOR-PASS"
     32834 HitPass        c 32823
     32834 VCL_call       c PASS
     32834 ReqHeader      c x-cache: pass
     32834 VCL_return     c fetch
     32834 Link           c bereq 32835 pass
     32834 Timestamp      c Fetch: 1585506205.155654 2.051945 2.051885
     32834 RespProtocol   c HTTP/1.1
     32834 RespStatus     c 200
     32834 RespReason     c OK
     32834 RespHeader     c Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400
     32834 RespHeader     c Content-Type: application/json
     32834 RespHeader     c Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
     32834 RespHeader     c Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
     32834 RespHeader     c X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
     32834 RespHeader     c X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
     32834 RespHeader     c Date: Sun, 29 Mar 2020 18:23:21 GMT
     32834 RespHeader     c Content-Length: 1499
     32834 RespHeader     c X-Varnish: 32834
     32834 RespHeader     c Age: 0
     32834 RespHeader     c Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
     32834 VCL_call       c DELIVER
     32834 ReqUnset       c x-cache: pass
     32834 ReqHeader      c x-cache: pass uncacheable
     32834 RespHeader     c x-cache: pass uncacheable
     32834 VCL_return     c deliver
     32834 Timestamp      c Process: 1585506205.155707 2.051998 0.000053
     32834 RespHeader     c Accept-Ranges: bytes
     32834 Debug          c "RES_MODE 2"
     32834 RespHeader     c Connection: keep-alive
     32834 Timestamp      c Resp: 1585506205.155740 2.052032 0.000034
     32834 ReqAcct        c 299 161 460 438 1499 1937
     32834 End            c
         0 CLI            - Rd ping
         0 CLI            - Wr 200 19 PONG 1585506205 1.0
         0 CLI            - Rd ping
         0 CLI            - Wr 200 19 PONG 1585506208 1.0
     32833 SessClose      c RX_TIMEOUT 7.072
     32833 End            c
```

As you can see **Debug: "XXX HIT-FOR-PASS"**

This is always coming, even though backend server has Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400

Varnish endpoint is returning 
*x-cache: pass uncacheable*

First response is 411 Length Required whereas subsequent response are successfull with 200 OK, but with X-Cache as 'pass uncacheable'.

What is it that I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
unset req.http.Cookie;
```

to `vcl_recv` section.

I think Varnish by default does not cache pages with Cookies.